# How can this Go code be faster than the C version

Tags: c, performance, go, optimization

The following programs are, as far as I can tell, identical. However, for small sizes (<30000), the go version is considerably faster.

```
Time taken for size 1000 in Go: 35.417µs
Time taken for size 1000 in C:  74.000000us
```

Architecture:
Darwin, arm64

The C code was compiled with the following command:

```bash
clang -O2 -march=native -mtune=native -g main.c
```

Go:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "math/rand"
   "time"
)

func ArraySplice(array []int, index int) []int {
   return append(array[:index], array[index+1:]...)
}

func main() {
   s := 1000;
   array := make([]int, s)

   for i := 0; i < s; i++ {
      array[i] = rand.Intn(s)
   }

   start := time.Now()
   for len(array) > 0 {
      array = ArraySplice(array, array[len(array)/2] % len(array))
   }
   end := time.Now()
   fmt.Printf("Time taken for size %d: %v\n", s, end.Sub(start))
}
```

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static inline size_t Array_Splice(int* array, size_t size, size_t index) {
   if (index >= size)
      return size;
   for (size_t i = index; i < size - 1; i++) {
      array[i] = array[i + 1];
   }
   return size - 1;
}

int main(void)
{
   const size_t size = 1000;
   size_t array_size = size;
   int* array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));
   if (array == NULL) {
      return 1;
   }

   for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      array[i] = rand() % size;
   }

   const clock_t start = clock();
   while (array_size > 0) {
      array_size = Array_Splice(array, array_size, array[array_size/2] % array_size);
   }
   const clock_t end = clock();
   const double time_taken = (double)(end - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000000.0f);
   printf("Time taken for size %lu: %fus\n", size, time_taken);

   free(array);
   return 0;
}
```

I have attempted to disassemble the code for both, but Go's assembly is quite hard to read.
The error is not in the timekeeping method, as the time to complete scales linearly with the array size.
Of note is that for larger arrays, C starts to pull ahead significantly, presumably due to increased GC calls.

Comment: Exactly how are you compiling the C program? You do use full optimization, right?

Comment: What do you mean with _increased GC calls_?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: _clang -O2 -march=native -mtune=native -g main.c._

Comment: You're splicing at random indices. I wouldn't expect this benchmark to deliver any stable results at all.

Comment: @Peter the values above are averaged across 10 runs. The c program gives more variance 60-100us vs the go program with 32-44us

Comment: @DavidRanieri GC -> Garbage Collection

Comment: @BogdanIonescu: Is the size of type int the same in C and Go?

Comment: @rocka2q I did not think of that :), they are not, go uses 64bit ints while c uses 32bit ints. However, switching to int64_t did not change the result.

Comment: @BogdanIonescu garbage collection in C?

Comment: @DavidRanieri to rephrase: C pulls ahead to due to Go's GC calls.

Comment: The reliable way to make any performance assertion is with profiling.  Without profiling or a vast expertise in the different runtimes, you're merely guessing.

Comment: @erik258 I have spent the last 3 days changing compilation commands, memory allocation strategies, looking at assembly and profiling methods. The example is reproducible.As mentioned, with larger sets of data, the expected result emerges( C is faster). I am looking for advice on how I could make the C code as fast for small data sets.

Comment: As I said, you're guessing.  You still haven't profiled.  But one thing comes to mind, you do update the array in C item by item.  I wonder if you could use https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html instead

Comment: @erik258 No need. It compiles into a `memmove` anyway.

Comment: @erik258 Thanks for the suggestion, `memmove()` did not provide any improvement. How would you profile this code? My profiling tools are not able to sample that fast, which is why I am using `clock_t`.

Comment: @BogdanIonescu As I said, your code already turned the ´for` loop into a `memmove`.

Comment: Are you sure the pseudo-random generator of Go and C is the same? If not, the different algorithms can also take part in the different benchmark results?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for actually trying the code. You are not resetting array_size back to size, so subsequent calls iterate over a 0 size array. The speed of execution does half after 10 loops, but i would expect something similar in Go. I am more interested in cold performance.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that. It's tricky to do optimizations on such short runs. An idling CPU needs time to speed up etc. and perhaps the Go program makes that happen before the performance measuring takes place. In that case, you wouldn't see much improvement if you run the Go test many times - but that's just speculation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That is accurate, doing the same in Go does not yield the same result. Go does spin up more threads, it uses 126% cpu vs C 96%. I think there is something to this, I will try to "warm" up the cpu before the c code runs.

Comment: I see. If Go is capable of parallelizing the splicing loop, it may be very hard to beat without doing the same in C.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `go` and its random number function(s) in particular.

But, I doubt that go's `math/rand` function `rand.Intn` will produce the same numbers as libc's `rand` function.

Ordinarily, the data wouldn't matter but we're using the random values as an index into the array to get the size/length of the array we're modifying.

That is, (e.g.) in the `go` program, we might use index 50 and the C program might use index 137.

Therefore, these index/size numbers *must* be the same for both programs. To verify this, we can print them out before using them. The outputs must match.

So, your `go` program and your C program are *not* equivalent tests.

We could spend a lot of time trying to find a [standard] C function that is equivalent to go's. But, an easier way is to write our own common/compatible function.

For the testing purposes here, the quality of the random function isn't much of an issue. A simple/reliable random function can be an LCG (linear congruential generator). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

We can create our own version(s) of this in the code as it's just a one-liner (e.g.):

```
seed = (seed * 1103515245) + 12345;
```

---

I've modified your program to [optionally] use a simple LCG instead of libc's `rand`.

You'll need to modify your `go` program equivalently.

Here is the modified program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned int seed = 1;
int opt_r;
int opt_p;

int
myrand(void)
{
    int val;

    // use LCG algorithm
    if (opt_r) {
        seed = (seed * 1103515245) + 12345;
        val = seed;
    }
    else
        val = rand_r(&seed);

    return val;
}

static inline size_t
Array_Splice(int *array, size_t size, size_t index)
{
    if (index >= size)
        return size;
    for (size_t i = index; i < size - 1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    return size - 1;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'r':
            opt_r = ! opt_r;
            break;
        case 'p':
            opt_p = ! opt_p;
            break;
        }
    }

    size_t size = 1000;
    if (--argc > 0)
        size = strtol(*argv++,NULL,10);
    printf("size=%zu\n",size);

    if (--argc > 0)
        seed = strtol(*argv++,NULL,10);
    printf("seed=%u\n",seed);

    size_t array_size = size;
    int *array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));

    if (array == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = myrand() % size;
        if (opt_p)
            printf("array[%zu]=%d\n",i,array[i]);
    }

    const clock_t start = clock();

    while (array_size > 0) {
        size_t array_index = array[array_size / 2] % array_size;
        if (opt_p)
            printf("array_index=%zu\n",array_index);
        array_size = Array_Splice(array, array_size, array_index);
    }
    const clock_t end = clock();
    const double time_taken = (double) (end - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000000.0f);

    printf("Time taken for size %lu: %fus\n", size, time_taken);

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Invoke with `-p` to print values (i.e. the timing will be meaningless).

Invoke with `-r` to use the LCG algorithm. Properly implemented [in `go`], the numbers will match with this option.

After that, the two programs *will* be making a meaningful timing comparison.

Comment: I have implemented your algorithm in both and saw no statistically significant difference.

Comment: @BogdanIonescu I suspect that would be the case you were trying to research. That go produces good code (i.e. as fast as C). Now, no matter the array size, you'll get similar timing results for each language.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, there was no significant difference between your random implementation and the standard library ones for both Go and C. In other words, the C variant is still 2x slower than the Go variant for small sets of data.